# How can I use (sed|awk) to mask an e-mail address with asterisks like <j******e@g***.com>

Tags: sed, awk, replace

How can I mask a list of e-mail addresses like:

```
John Doe <john.doe@gmail.com>
John Doe <johndoe@hotmail.net>
Jane Doe <j.doe@outlook.org>
```

... with sed (or awk) into something like:

```
John Doe <j******e@g***l.com>
John Doe <j*****e@h*****l.net>
Jane Doe <j***e@o*****k.org>
```

In other words: replace most of the e-mail address with asterisks but make it somehow recognizable by users who know the actual e-mail address.

Comment: just a note, `jd@co.cc` is a perfectly valid email address that, when thusly encoded, would be rendered as `jd@co.cc`...

Answer (score 2):

Another Perl version:

```
perl -pe 's/(<.)(.*)(@.)(.*)(.\..*>)/$1."*" x length($2).$3."*" x length($4).$5/e'
```

Example:

```
$ perl -pe 's/(<.)(.*)(@.)(.*)(.\..*>)/$1."*" x length($2).$3."*" x length($4).$5/e' foo
John Doe <j*******@g***l.com>
John Doe <j******@h*****l.net>
Jane Doe <j****@o*****k.org>
```

With `sed`, replacing the characters by an equal number of `*` is complicated. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16005578/2072269) for examples involving `sed`, `perl` and `awk`.

Comment: I guess to truly answer the original poster you need a slight tweak: `(.@.)`, plus I'm not sure the `\..*` is good enough in case there are subdomains.

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -pe '
    sub asteriskify {
        my $s = shift;
        substr $s, 1, -1, "*" x (length($s) - 2);
        return $s
    }
    s/<(.*)@(.*)(?=\..*>)/
        "<" . asteriskify($1) . "@" . asteriskify($2)
    /e;
' < input > output
```

The [substr](http://p3rl.org/substr) replaces characters in the string from the second one to the last but one by dots, the number of the dots being the length of the string - 2.

The substitution captures the username to $1 and the domain name without the final part to $2, the `?=` part just makes sure it's followed by a dot, whatever and `>` (see Look Around Assertions in [perlre](http://p3rl.org/perlre)).

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked how to do it with awk, I thought I would prove that it was not too hard. So here goes:

```
echo "John Doe <john.doe@gmail.com> John Doe <johndoe@hotmail.net> Jane Doe <j.doe@outlook.org>" | \
awk \
'
{print repl($0)}

function repl(s, m)
{
  if (match(s,"(<.)([^>]*)(.@.)([^>]*)(.\\.[a-z]*>)", m))
  {
    return substr(s, 1, RSTART-1) m[1] \
           gensub(".","*","g",m[2]) m[3] \
           gensub(".","*","g",m[4]) m[5] \
           repl(substr(s,RSTART+RLENGTH))
  }
  else
    return s
}
'
```

Answer (score 0):

using sed:

```
sed 's/.$//' foo.txt | sed 's#\<\(.\).*\(.@.\).*\(\..*\)#\1***\2***\3#'
```

first sed get rid of the ending >, and 2nd sed will mask the mail address.

output

```
J****e@g****.com
J****e@h****.net
J****e@o****.org
```

Comment: You could shorten that to `sed 's#\<\(.\).*\(.@.\).*\(\..*\)\>#\1***\2***\3#' foo.txt` and save one sed-process.