# how to mask email address joebl**@******.*** using sed/awk/grep/etc

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep, email

I have some emails where I would like to mask all characters except the last 2 before the @ sign and mask everything after that.

For example:

```
<joeblow@joeblow.com>
```

Desired output:

```
<joebl**@******.***>
```

So far, using `perl`, I tried:

```
perl -pe 's/(<.)(.*)(@.)(.*)(.\..*>)/$1."*" x length($2).$3."*" x length($4).$5/e'
```

but it is not giving the intended results.

Comment: it's similar, but i couldn't post a question on there so i created a new question.

Comment: Dang Tran, why is it only "similar" rather than a duplicate?

Comment: @roaima i'm not too familiar with the perl -pe command.  i dont' know what it does or how it works.  i simply copied/paste into my command to get my result, but it's masking more than i intended but i dont know how to modify to fit my needs,  thanks

Comment: @DangTran Please say so in your question then, referencing the other question and noting how it differs from yours.

Comment: Your question seems to be garbled. You say “I would like to mask all characters except the last 2 before the ```@``` sign”, but then you show an example masking the last 2 before the ```@``` sign and *leaving* all characters except the last 2 before the ```@``` sign *alone*.  Also, you say “… and mask everything after that”, but then you show the **```.```** not being masked.

Comment: @roaima: In Dang Tran’s defense, this question is clearly different from the other one in that it has different parameters (last two vs. first and last).   And I agree that that’s a lousy reason to deny that another question is a duplicate.   But, I look at the answers to the other question, and I see no way to change them to use different parameters — they are “too localized”, and lack the explanation that would allow a novice user to generalize them.   (Sure, I could probably figure it out if I applied myself for two minutes.)  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  If we’re not going to allow Dang Tran to post a follow-up question on the other thread  (either as an answer or a comment),  then we have to allow them to ask a new question.

Comment: @G-Man if it's not a duplicate then by all means the OP should ask a new question. I was asking for the OP to explain why it wasn't, so that better answers might be offered here.

Comment: Ugh. Another user and I voted to close as unclear, for me on the basis of conflicting details in the question as @G-Man state's above. However, three others voted it as dupe, which I disagree with, but U/L claims I voted for. Dang Tran, if you can edit it to clarify exactly what you want, then I'd vote to re-open.

Comment: @Sparhawk: Yeah, it’s weird. OK, it always states the majority reason as ***the*** close reason. But sometimes it lists who voted for that reason, and then the others separately, and sometimes it lists all five as if they had unanimously agreed with the majority reason.

Comment: @G-Man Huh… okay. That is very strange. I only really remember listing everyone together, but maybe that's just my bad memory.

Comment: `sed -e 'h;s/.*@//;x' -e 's/..@.*//;x' -e 's/[^.>]/*/g' -e 'H;g;s/\n/**@/' ` will perform the transformation you're looking for.

Comment: @Sparhawk OK, I found an example: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/470793/ambiguous-redirect-for-stdin-to-while-loop. See [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Nqw5.png) (in case the question gets deleted or reopened). … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  The text says «**put on hold** as off-topic by Stephen Harris, Vlastimil, Goro, Thomas, RalfFriedl 10 hours ago // This question appears to be off-topic.  The users who voted to close gave this specific reason: // • "Questions describing **a problem that can't be reproduced** and seemingly went away on its own (or went away when a typo was fixed) are off-topic as they are unlikely to help future readers." – Stephen Harris, Vlastimil, Goro, Thomas».  So apparently RalfFriedl voted for a different close reason.  But this is the first one I’ve seen in ten days.

Comment: @Sparhawk: It never rains but it pours; [here’s](https://superuser.com/q/1356881/354511 "Eyes killing me after purchasing laptop") another one. DrMoishe Pippik is a close voter, but is not listed under the majority close reason.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to understand what the solutions given to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243343/how-can-i-use-sedawk-to-mask-an-e-mail-address-with-asterisks-like-je) *very similar* question mean, and adapt them to your case. I understand that if you never met Perl before this can be quite a challenge, though. So, here's your solution:

```
echo joeblow@joeblow.com | perl -pe 's#..@(.*)#"**@".$1=~s/[^.]/*/gr#e'
joebl**@*******.***
```

Now, go and learn...

---

The question was edited and the input data changed. Here's an updated answer:

```
echo '<joeblow@joeblow.com>' | perl -pe 's#..@(.*)#"**@".$1=~s/[^.>]/*/gr#e'
<joebl**@*******.***>
```

Comment: This is good: allow for any number of dots in the domain part.

Comment: thank you simlev.  my input has the closing > at the end so the domain part has 4 **** instead of ***.  input <joeblow@joeblow.com>

Comment: @DangTran Just add a ">" then. Please note that your posted input is `joeblow@joeblow.com`: you should edit your question with any further info.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ perl -pe 's/(.*)(..)(@)(.*)(\.)(.*)(>)/$1."*" x length($2).$3."*" x length($4).$5 ."*" x length($6).$7/e' file
<joebl**@*******.***>
```

Never used `perl`, but I can kludge my way through regex.

Match any character as many times as possible:

```
(.*)
```

Match two characters:

```
(..)
```

Literal `@` symbol

```
(@)
```

Literal `.`

```
(\.)
```

Then replace those matches with something. We want to keep the first group (the first 5 characters), so just print it:

```
$1
```

And print a `*` for each character we found in the second group:

```
"*" x length($2)
```

The rest follows similarly.

Comment: Good explanation!

Comment: @Kevin Kruse thanks for this.  very helpful.  my input is:  <joeblow@joeblow.com>.  so the output has the extra * at the end due to this closing/greater than sign >.

Comment: @DangTran that's different from the text in your question. Do you want to print the brackets in the output as well? e.g. `<joebl**@*******.***>` ?

Comment: yes i do Kevin.  i'm trying to navigate through this site and learn and find the edit button to edit my post.  thanks all for understanding.

Comment: I'll edit my answer. You can use this [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/468515/edit) link (found near the bottom of your question) to edit your post. Please include brackets in the input and output when you edit.

Answer (score 2):

If obfuscation is your goal, you might not want to give the viewer any clues about the string length of the TLD and domain: try using just a fixed number of stars:

```
perl -pe 's/..\@.*/**\@******/g'
```

---

Update based on revised requirements I read through the comments:

```
email="blah blah <joeblow@jowblow.com> blah blah <ginger@far.side.larson>"

echo "$email" | perl -pe 's/<.*?\K..\@[^>]+/**\@****/g'
```

```
blah blah <joebl**@****> blah blah <ging**@****>
```

Or with simlev's idea of keeping the dots:

```
$ perl -pe 's{<.*?\K..\@([^>]+)}{ ($tmp = $1) =~ s/[^.]/*/g; "**\@$tmp" }eg' <<<"$email"
blah blah <joebl**@*******.***> blah blah <ging**@***.****.******>
```

Comment: your comment formatting is a bit messed up, but since perl performs variable interpolation on both sides of the s/// command, we don't want the `@` interpreted as the start of an array variable. As for the `g` the content of the input is unknown: although the `.*` will slurp up the rest of the line.

Comment: Yeah, the comment formatting didn't come out as expected! Thanks for the explanation, I guess it's just safer this way. Totally agree on the suggestion to not preserve the original string length, although there might be a case for both options as it really depends on the purpose.