# Ambiguous redirect for stdin to while loop

Tags: bash, io-redirection, cut

I would like to run a command for each entry in a column of a file. I am currently doing the following, but am getting an ambiguous redirect error.

```
while read -r entry;
do
  cmd "$entry" ;
done < $(cut -f2 file.tsv)
```

I've also tried

```
done <(cut -f2 file.tsv)
```

which throws an unexpected token syntax error.

What is the correct syntax for doing this?

---

### Example Input

A tab separated values file with file paths in the column of interest.

```
1    file1.txt    ...
2    file2.txt    ...
3    file3.txt    ...
```

### Expected Result

The script should run the commands

```
cmd file1.txt
cmd file2.txt
cmd file3.txt
```

For the purpose of a simple example, you can use `cat` as the `cmd`, since the error is not with the `cmd` *per se*, but with the input redirection.

The actual command I am running is the bioinformatics tool [kallisto](https://pachterlab.github.io/kallisto/manual#quant), specifically `kallisto quant`.

Comment: Please state the actual command in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is the right way to do it:

```
while read -r entry;
do
  cmd "$entry" ;
done < <(cut -f2 file.tsv)
```

According to [this bash redirection cheat sheet](http://www.catonmat.net/download/bash-redirections-cheat-sheet.pdf), this syntax passes the output of `cut -f2 file.tsv` to an anonymous fifo, then passes that to stdin.

Comment: Would really appreciate to know why this is getting downvoted.  Personally, I find this more readable than [Goro's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/470798/148899).

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be revised as follows:

```
cut -f2  file.tsv | while read -a entry;
do
  cmd "$entry" ;

done
```

Please note, whenever you run a shell script, it creates a new process called subshell and your script will get executed using a subshell. However, a Subshell can be used to do parallel processing. If you start another shell on top of your current shell, it can be referred to as a subshell. Type the following command to see subshell value:

```
echo $BASH_SUBSHELL
```

OR

```
echo "Current shell: $BASH_SUBSHELL"; ( echo "Running du in subshell: $BASH_SUBSHELL" ;cd /tmp; du 2>/tmp/error 1>/tmp/output)
```

Any commands enclosed within parentheses are run in a subshell.

Comment: Note that in `bash`, the `cmd` is run in a subshell and so any variables and related values won't be set.  The original command (if done correctly) is run in the current shell.

Comment: @StephenHarris, just making sure I follow: You're saying input redirection doesn't trigger a subshell, but piping does?

Comment: Using a pipe causes the `while` loop (and so `cmd`) to be run in a subshell.  Using redirection means that the `while` loop is run in the parent process.